# Remove duplicate in an array[string]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a `dataframe` column with `array` of `string` as below. (Key,value) pair

```
ColA
[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)]
```

I have to remove duplicate keys by min value and get the results. 
Dont want to explode and do it. Key should be unique and the key is picked based on the min value. In the above column, there are three pairs with key as 1. So should pick (1,2) since value 2 is min among (1,2),(1,3),(1,4)

Output should be:
    ColA
    [(1,2),(2,3)]

I created a udf like

```
Val removeDup = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => {
Arr.map(x=>x.split(","))}))
```

Cannot use `reduceby` key as its a `dataframe`/`dataset`.

Comment: Can you clearly state the input dataframe column?

Comment: It has only one column in a dataframe

Comment: How do you get ColA (1,2),(2,3) if you take minimum value ?

Comment: Edited with more explanation

Comment: @Deek can you provide sample input data for the dataframe you have?

Comment: I'm confused about your types. You write that `(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)` is of type `Seq[String]`, but in your `udf` you call `split` indicating that it is type `String` and not `Seq[String]`. What is the type of the column?

Comment: String is the type of the column

Comment: Can you execute `dataframe.printSchema` and edit your question with the output? What's the Spark version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so provided that the column if of type `String` and *not* type `Seq[String]`, the code below should give you what you want:

```
val removeDup = udf((str: String) => {
  str.split("\\(|\\)").filter(s => s != "," && s != "").map(s => {
    val array = s.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")
    (array(0), array(1))
  })
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(a => a.sortBy(_._2).head)
  .values
  .toSeq
  .sortBy(_._1)
})
```

On your example:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3)").toDF("colA")

df.select(removeDup('colA)).show
```

this yields

```
+--------------------+
|           UDF(colA)|
+--------------------+
|      [[1,2], [2,3]]|
+--------------------+
```

If you wish to keep the column type as `String`, you would need to add `.mkString(",")` to the `udf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select("v1","v2").groupby("v2").min("v2").show­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
```

Comment: Its a single column with array for string. This might not help!